# Cannot retract a single handed close vote

Tags: support, vote-to-close, dupehammer, vote-to-reopen

I just close voted a question and as I have enough privilege, the qustion was immediately closed.
So far so good.

But then I realized that I shouldn't have close voted, but it's impossible to retract the close vote. I can edit the close vote and remove the duplicate, but then the "Save" button remains inactive.

IMO the Save button should be active in that case.

I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature.

Comment: You should be able to click on the "reopen" button and it should single-handed be reopened.

Comment: No one can retract a close vote once the question is closed.  That is by design.  All you can do is vote to reopen, and a gold badge holder such as yourself can instantly reopen a question closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @psubsee2003 unless in the very unlikely case you've re-opened for any reason before in which case you can't reopen again...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can only retract a vote if it hasn't yet had an effect.

So if you don't have a close badge then you can retract a close vote only if you're not the last close voter. If you do have a gold badge then you're always the last close voter as your close vote takes effect immediately i.e. the question is summarily closed.

You do have a way out though as a gold badge holder, you can vote to reopen and that vote will take effect immediately too, the question will be summarily reopened.